# Declaring WebBrowser in VB.NET Other Form

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I am working on a project that has WebBrowsers in Other Forms;
I wrote the code below to control these WebBrowsers; but I need the code to recognize (Declare) the WebBrowsers of these forms.

```
Dim openForm As Form = Nothing
For Index As Integer = My.Application.OpenForms.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1
    openForm = My.Application.OpenForms.Item(Index)
    If openForm IsNot Me Then
         MyWebBrowser.navigate("http://www.google.com/") ' PROBLEM IN THIS LINE
    End If
Next
```

My Module created them as below:

```
Module MMMBrowser
   Dim frmNew As New Form
   Dim MekdamBrowser As New WebBrowser
```

Comment: I didnt know you already had form refs - makes my answer obsolete. If frmNew is supposed to be a reference to the main form which you said was Form2, then the first line should be `Friend frmNew As Form2`.  I dont know which is the class name on the second, but it would be something like `Friend MekdamBrowser As WebBroweser`.  Does your app start with a main form or is there also a Sub Main?

Comment: Yes Plutonix; My application starts in Form1 then it calls Form2 which then uses the Module to create New forms including New Browsers. and I am trying to manipulate the newly created webbrowser from Form2.

Comment: No, the module does not create forms for you - it is just making the references available to the app - they are not set to anything.  those lines should be: `FRIEND ... As Form1` and `FRIEND ... As Form2`

Comment: No, the Module simply provides the frmNew and MekdamBrowser, then show them and navigate in the MekdamBrowser; but the piece I want to add is to do more manipulations from Form2, to those browsers. Form2, call this Module many times.

Comment: Thanks a lot; Like I want to check "MekdamBrowser" contents and extract texts from these browsers while I am in Form2; so the only issue I am facing is how to access these browsers from Form2. As I do not want to do that from "frmNew". Much appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other info gleaned from comments:

- there is form factory of some sort which creates new `frmNew`
- there are many of these open at a time, which is the reason for the backwards loop thru `OpenForms` to find the last one.
- The `MekdamBrowser` reference is an attempt to refer to the browser on the form.

The easy things is to provide a way for outsiders to tell the form to navigate somewhere using a new `Sub`, and let the form drive the browser control.  This probably eliminates the need for a global MekdamBrowser reference.   In the browser form add something like this:

```
Public Sub GotoNewURL(url As String)
   myWebBrowserName.navigate(url)
End Sub
```

This procedure only exists for `Form1` not the generic `Form` type, so we need to change how you find the form to use.  Your existing loop is wonky.  It will only ever find the last instance of a form which is not the current form.  If you add a third form type, it wont work well:

```
Dim lastBrowserFrm As Form1         ' use the class name!

' this will try to get the last Instance of Form1 
lastBrowserFrm = Application.OpenForms.OfType(Of Form1)().LastOrDefault

' LastOrDefaultcan return nothing if there are none,
' so test
If lastBrowserFrm IsNot Nothing Then      
     lastBrowserFrm .GotoNewUrl("www.stackoverflow.com")
Else
    ' create a new one, I guess
End If
```

Your loop was not considering that there could be other form types in the collection which are not `Form1` or even if a new browser form was the last one created!  This is more important now because `GotoNewURL` is only available on `Form1` instances.

I changed the name to `lastBrowserFrm` to reflect what is really going one - it will just find the last one created.  If you are trying to work with a *specific* instance, you need to provide a way to track the ones you create such as with a `List(of Form1)` or use the Name property so you can tell one from the other.  As is, you do not a way to get back a specific form instance.

Comment: Thanks a lot Plutonix; Very elaborated response; I will try it now. Seems I need to do some more manipulations that I've expected.

Comment: Plutonix; I already have a module that creates both form (frmNew) and WebBrowser (MMMBrowser); \when I added this line to the |Module, I got error: Friend MMMBrowser As frmNew; I tried to move the line (Dim frmNew As New Form) above that line, but did not help. Any idea?

Comment: It said: "Type frmNew" is not defined; even though I defined it as "Dim frmNew As New Form". In my original Module I used: (Dim frmNew As New Form) then (Dim MekdamBrowser As New WebBrowser)

Comment: My Main Form called "Form2" and the Module created a form called "frmNew" and new browser called "MekdamBrowser" as per my edits above.

Comment: "frmNew" are bunch of new forms each contains "MekdamBrowser"; they were created and shown "frmNew.Show()"; the original Module include "Dim frmNew As New Form" when I replace the Dim with "Friend frmMain As Form2"; I got error on the using of "frmNew" inside the Module; the error is: "Error 'frmNew' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level."

Comment: Yes the Module has just simple code; like sizing "frmNew" and "MekdamBrowser", and navigating in "MekdamBrowser" and "frmNew.Show"; and there are few of "frmNew" opened at the same time.